# Assign a ui element to another ui element from another thread in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I want to make a grid element in wpf programmatically with c# code and because it needs a huge processing  i used a thread for it.now when i want to assign it the visual studio says :

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it."

my code is something like this :

```
PrepareGrid gridMaker = new PrepareGrid();
Thread fetchGrid = new Thread(() => {
    GridContainer.Dispacher.Invoke(() => GridContainer.Content = gridMaker.getGrid());
});
fetchGrid.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
fetchGrid.Start();
```

`PrepareGrid` is a class that prepares the grid and its `getGrid`'s method returns the result grid and `GridContainer` is a WPF Scroll Viewer

i used nested dispatchers but it doesn't work

---

Why i can't use `Task` for wpf elements? the process of making grid is so huge and   `Thread` uses only one core of processor as i know

Comment: I'm curious: did you make _any_ effort at all to research this question on your own? Bottom line: WPF UI objects have to be created in the same thread where they will be used. But also bottom line: you should not be creating UI objects in code-behind anyway. WPF has a very useful and efficient data binding model, which you can use to your advantage by creating _data_ object in a background thread, and then updating the UI in the UI thread once you're done with that. In the event that update is still time-consuming, you can take steps to do it incrementally so the UI remains responsive.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes i did a lot of researches but non of them was my actual answer,what are those binding models?

Comment: See "MVVM", for starters.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, you can have multiple UI threads, but a UI element must be used on the thread where it's created. You're creating it in the other thread, right? So you can't use it in the default UI thread.

I suspect the "huge processing" is not from the mere creation of the actual UI object at all. Find out exactly what the "huge processing" consists of, and put *that* on another thread. Or have your other thread invoke into the main UI thread when it creates the actual control or controls.

Comment: the grid is so large and many elements should insert into it so i want to the program being responsive until the grid is getting ready and a grid should be created that thread

Comment: @Javad Do you have a viewmodel?